# Implementing U-Net segmentation model without padding

Tags: keras, cnn, image-segmentation

I'm trying to implement the U-Net CNN as per the published paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04597.pdf).

I've followed the paper architecture as closely as possible but I'm hitting an error when trying to carry out the first concatenation:

[image]

From the diagram, it appears the 8th Conv2D should be merged with result of the 1st UpSampling2D operation, however the `Concatenate()` operation throws an exception that the shapes don't match:

```
def model(image_size = (572, 572) + (1,)):

    # Input / Output layers
    input_layer = Input(shape=(image_size), 32)

    """ Begin Downsampling """

    # Block 1
    conv_1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu')(input_layer)
    conv_2 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu')(conv_1)

    max_pool_1 = MaxPool2D(strides=2)(conv_2)

    # Block 2
    conv_3 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu')(max_pool_1)
    conv_4 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu')(conv_3)

    max_pool_2 = MaxPool2D(strides=2)(conv_4)

    # Block 3
    conv_5 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu')(max_pool_2)
    conv_6 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu')(conv_5)

    max_pool_3 = MaxPool2D(strides=2)(conv_6)

    # Block 4
    conv_7 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu')(max_pool_3)
    conv_8 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu')(conv_7)

    max_pool_4 = MaxPool2D(strides=2)(conv_8)

    """ Begin Upsampling """

    # Block 5
    conv_9 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu')(max_pool_4)
    conv_10 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu')(conv_9)

    upsample_1 = UpSampling2D()(conv_10)

    # Connect layers
    merge_1 = Concatenate()([conv_8, upsample_1])
```

Error:

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(32, 64, 64, 512), (32, 56, 56, 1024)]
```

Note that the values `64` and `56` correctly line up with the architecture.

[image]

I don't understand how to implement the model as it is in the paper. If I change my code to accept an image of shape `(256, 256)` and add `padding='same'` to the Conv2D layers, the code works as the sizes are aligned.

This seems to go against what the authors specifically state in their implementation:

[image]

Could somebody point me in the right direction on the correct implementation of this model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

If we follow the definition of each arrow.

*Gray => Copy and* **Crop**

> *Every step in the expansive path consists of an upsampling of the
> feature map followed by a 2x2 convolution (“up-convolution”) that halves the
> number of feature channels, a **concatenation with the correspondingly cropped
> feature map** from the contracting path, and two 3x3 convolutions, each followed by a ReLU. The cropping is necessary due to the loss of border pixels in
> every convolution. <sub>**Paper**</sub>*

So, believe(*I have added 3 coloured circles*)

- **Blue** - *28x28 is upsampled and become 56x56, 1024 is halved to 512*
- **Red** - *64x64 is cropped to 56x56. Then Concatenated along FM axis.*
- **Black** - *3x3 convolutions, followed by a ReLU*

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that makes sense. I'll look into cropping in Keras later and update when I get a solution.